# .net framework - file version seems to be OS specific?

Tags: .net, .net-2.0

why is the *file version* of the assemblies included in the .net framework 2.0 different on individual machines?

i have two systems, both with most recent microsoft patches and updates.

for this example i'll look at dotnet 2.0 (x86):

- windows xp (x86) has System.Windows.Forms.dll - 2.0.50727.**3637**
- windows 7 (x64) has System.Windows.Forms.dll - 2.0.50727.**5460**

what's the pattern behind the different file version?

- is it OS specific (xp vs. 7)?
- is it platform specific (x86 vs. x64)?
- is it language specific?

--

**[edit]**
to make the question more clear: it seems that microsoft was installing different "flavours" of the dotnet framework.
i'd like to understand the **rules** that apply. something like:

- **flavour A** gets installed on target systems **X**
- **flavour B** gets installed on target systems **Y**

in case you have ever authored an msi yourself you'll understand what i have in mind with a "condition" in the "component" table, for example.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's OS-specific.

From MSDN: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2686831.

```
This article applies to the following:   
Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 when used with:
     Windows 7 Service Pack 1
     Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1
```

and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2686828

```
This article applies to the following:
Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2 when used with:
    Windows XP Service Pack 3
    Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.
as far as i understood you're guessing / drawing conclusions from the KB comments "this article applies to".

however, i'd appreciate to have the official pattern / logic uncovered.
i tried to decompile the framework installer, for example. but i got stuck as the dotnet 2.0 SP2 installer is quite a complex mix of *.msi, *.msp, *.mst. there is no single *.msi we can easily analyze with orca.

Comment: I'm not guessing. The articles I link to give the exact files that will be installed for security update **MS12-038**. As you can see from the linked articles, the files are different for different OSes. Note that there are other versions of System.Windows.Forms.dll for other OSes (e.g. Windows 8 : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2686837).